# How to download Google Chart API?

Tags: php, html, graph, google-visualization, phpgraphlib

I am using Google Chart in one my Program, The program will run locally and have no internet access to use Google Charts. Can you please tell me where can i download the Library, I searched on net but failed to find out any possible way to download it?

Thanks

Comment: The Visualization API is not available offline.  Mirroring/local hosting is actually explicitly forbidden by the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the google chart API from the following link:

https://www.google.com/jsapi

Just hit the URL on your browser and save it by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
And include it in your project.

For more information [see here for offline chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq?csw=1#offline).

**EDITED:**

this library used two online library also so you need to download then and change the path:

```
google.loader.ServiceBase = 'https://www.google.com/uds';
google.loader.GoogleApisBase = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax';
```

In the above line you can see those libraries.

Comment: I did that, but it still go to the internet to draw graph..

Comment: Thanks..let me check this

Comment: It said that you can not use these libraries offline?

Comment: @user3480644 check these library is there any check or any other parent library.